# regex: filter out certain words AND also a word where a part changes depending on user

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to construct a regex that filters out certain words. That I was thinking of doing with the below regex:

```
/^(source-compliance|i18nextLng|userToken)$/.test(str);
```

However, an new value needs to be added. We have for example 'pinned-homepage-46488645' the number part is an example of a user-id, so it's never the same number. How can I add pinned-homepage + followed by number to this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `-` by using `\` in your regex expression.

```js
var str ='pinned-homepage-46488645';
var result =/^(source-compliance|i18nextLng|userToken|pinned\-homepage\-\d+)$/.test(str);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You didn't had to escape `-` in `source-compliance` but had to escape in `pinned-homepage-46488645`. Please don't mislead people by writing incorrect things. You don't need to escape a hyphen `-` in regex, just `\d+` instead of exact number was enough.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi then you can post an answer that you think is correct,in my opinion,we do not need to escape it in the test string

Comment: Your usage of `\d+` for making it any number is correct. But what you've highlighted and started your answer saying `You need to escape - by using \ in your regex expression.` is NOT CORRECT and many people reading that will get mis-informed that they will need to escape a hyphen which isn't true. Try un-escaping hyphen in your regex and you will see it still works.